# CSS - Floating Elements WIthin Range

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make it so that the floating content ontop of my slider will get smaller with the page as you change the size of your browser. For example if you take your browser and change the size of it so that its only taking up half your monitors space it will shrink everything to scale.

So far the whole page is doing that, its just my slider that isn't doing it correctly.

Link: http://skipq.net/app/indextest.php

Code:

```
        <div class="flexslider">
          <ul class="slides">
            <li><img src="http://skipq.net/app/images/banner1.png" />
              <div class="context">
              <div class="context-inn"><h2>This app is money.</h2>
              <span class="description">Use our new app to pay at your favorite stores.<br />
When it comes time to check out,<br />
choose how you want to pay in a few taps.</span>
<div class="banner-form" id="banner-form1">Paying is easier with our new app<br />
  <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">    
    <input type="text" name="keywords" id="keywords" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Mobile number (ex. 555-555-5555)';" onfocus="if(this.value=='Mobile number (ex. 555-555-5555)') this.value='';" value="Mobile number (ex. 555-555-5555)" alt="Mobile number (ex. 555-555-5555)"><br />
       <div style="display:none;" id="carrierSelection">
          <select name="carrier" style="font">
           <option value="Verizon">Verizon</option>
           <option value="AT_and_T">AT&T</option>
           <option value="Sprint">Sprint</option>
           <option value="T_Mobile">T-Mobile</option>
        </select> 
      </div>
    <input type="button" name="button" id="chbutton" value="Choose Your Carrier" />

  </form>
<span class="note">By continuing, you confirm this is your number and agree to receive a text. Standard messaging rates apply.</span>
<ul class="mobileicons">
<li class="android">Android</li>
<li class="iphone">iPhone</li>
</ul>
</div></div></div>
            </li>
            <li> <img src="http://skipq.net/app/images/banner2.png" />
              <div class="context"><div class="context-inn"><h2>More time is more money.</h2>
              <span class="description">When you sell online with PayPal and offer financing <br />
with Bill Me Laterｮ, your buyers can get even more. <br />
You get paid up front, they get up to 6 months to pay.<br />
<span class="font11">Subject to credit approval. <a href="#">See Terms</a></span> </span>
<div class="banner-form">Sell more online with us<br />
  <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">    
    <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Start Offering Financing" />
  </form>
</div></div></div>
            </li>
            <li> <img src="http://skipq.net/app/images/banner3.png" />
              <div class="context"><div class="context-inn"><h2>Tap into savings <br />
at hundreds of stores.</h2>
              <span class="description">Enjoy savings up to 40% off at hundreds of your <br />
favorite stores every day on PayPal Shopping.</span>
<div class="banner-form">Save at more stores with us<br />
  <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">    
    <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Shop the Deals" />
  </form>
</div></div></div>
            </li>
            <li> <img src="http://skipq.net/app/images/banner4.png" />
              <div class="context"><div class="context-inn"><h2>Take six months off.</h2>
              <span class="description">We bought you some extra time to pay<br />
on anything over $99. Bill Me Laterｮ<br />
is subject to credit approval. <a href="#">See Terms</a></span>
<div class="banner-form">A little time goes a long way<br />
  <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">    
    <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Start Offering Financing" />
  </form>
</div></div></div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Let me know what code you need to detect where the issue is!

Comment: Use Bootstrap http://getbootstrap.com

Comment: I am using Bootstrap, if you're using Chrome goto the developer options click network and refresh the page. It will show all the resources being used.

Comment: Please post the related code so that we might be able to help easier. Only linking to the webpage is against the question rules

Comment: Sorry about that @Zeaklous I'll add the code right now!